# Is this character causing the graphics path error?

Tags: graphics, errors, texstudio

I have a graphics path:

> \graphicspath{{C:/Users/Username/Documents/Project 1 - Project
>   Title/Project Writeup/Project/Graphics}}

That is not working:

> File 'Figure' not found. \inclulegraphics{Figure}

However, this was directly copied from another latex file which definitely works. The only modification was the graphics path itself, the length of the graphics path and the little "-" thing between 'Project 1' and 'Project'.

In the tex file which the graphics path was working, it was written as:

> \graphicspath{{C:/Users/Username/Documents/Project/Graphics}}

I am speculating that either the file path is too long, or that the "-" is causing some unexpected error.

Can someone verify that maybe the case so I need to change the folder's name to omit the "-" or shorter the path length

Comment: don't have spaces in file (or folder) names (or if you really must, quote the path with `"..."`)

Comment: Also the graphics path segments should end in `/`  so `\graphicspath{{C:/Users/Username/Documents/Project/Graphics/}}`

Comment: The "no spaces" rule is always a good one in paths on computers, not just for Latex. Yeah, we're not there yet. Alternatively, place the graphics in the same folder as your .tex file, then you only need the name of the file without the extension, so if you have `picture1.png`, then you can include it using `\includegraphics{picture1}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-` won't be the problem (unless you are using a language that declares it to be a babel shortcut) but spaces in filenames are evil:-) If you must have spaces, it probably works to quote them as

```
\graphicspath{%
{"C:/Users/Username/Documents/Project 1 - Project Title/Project Writeup/Project/Graphics/"}%
}
```

but not having spaces is good. Also the `grffile` package has some extensions to `graphicx` to help with weird filenames.